# Using a parabola for interpolation

Tags: linear-algebra, conic-sections

I am trying to use a parabola to interpolate between 3 values and I have been struggling with finding an equation that works for me.

The constraints are:

- passes through the points $(0, s), (x,m), (1, n)$ [$x$ is not given, but must be between $0$ and $1$]
- $0 < s < 1$
- $0 < m < 1$
- $0 < n < 1$
- $0 < x < 1$
- $x$ is the x-coordinate of the maximum/minimum of the parabola
- $m > s$ and $m > n$ or $m < s$ and $m < n$ ($m$ will never be between $s$ and $n$)

In the standard $y = ax^2 + bx + c$ form, I have been able to determine:

- $c = s$
- $a + b + c = n$
- $c - \frac{b^2}{4a} = m$
- $n - s = a + b$
- $a = \frac{b^2}{ 4*(s - m)}$

I always seem to come out with 2 possible values for $b$ (due to a $\pm \sqrt{...}$), and only one of those will give me a maximum/minimum between $0$ and $1$. I am almost certain that there is a way to determine $a$, $b$, and $c$ from the given $s$, $n$, and $m$.

I have been slamming my head against a wall for the past week and a half trying to figure this out.

EDIT: I have gotten the equation to a point where all I need to do is calculate $a$ from the inputs $s$,$n$, and $m$.

Comment: Are you trying to find a,b,c values while s,x,m,n are given?

Comment: @corbah. Essentially, yes. The only issue is that x is not given. I need to find a, b, and c from the inputs s, n, and m

Comment: If the parabola's axis is vertical, the problem is overconstrained. From the fact that $(x_0,m)$ is a minimum or maximum (using the symbol $x_0$ here rather than $x$ because it's really bad form to use the same symbol for both the general horizontal coordinate and a particular coordinate), you know that the parabola has an equation in the form $y = k(x - x_0)^2 + m$ for some constant $k,$ and from the fact that the parabola passes through $(0,s)$ you can determine $k.$ At that point the parabola is fully determined and might or might not also pass through $(1,n).$

Comment: My previous comment was based on the assumption that $x_0$ was known. I see that was a mistake. The unknown $x_0$ is the degree of freedom needed to make this problem solvable.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a vertical parabola $\;f(x)=y=ax^2+bx+c\;$ then it may be easier. Since $\;(0,s)\;$ is on it, we get $\;s=f(0)=c\;$ ,and also:

$$n=f(1)=a+b+c=a+b+s\implies a+b=n-s$$

and since $\;(x_0,m)\;$ (changed the notation for convenience) is the parabola's vertex, we get that

$$\begin{cases}x_0=-\frac b{2a}\\{}\\m=-\frac{\Delta}{4a}=-\frac{b^2-4ac}{4a}=-\frac{b^2}{4a}+s\end{cases}$$

Solving the above

$$b=-2ax_0\implies m=-\frac{4a^2x_0^2}{4a}+s=-ax_0^2+s\implies a=\frac{s-m}{x_0^2}$$

and you have all your parabola's coefficient in function of the given points.

Comment: Thank you. You did re-state many of the equations in my initial post. (i.e. s = c). With the solution you posted, since my only inputs are s, n, and m, how can we get $x_0$ from those values?

Comment: @ChaseWalden You already have in the very last line expressions for $\;x_0\;$ depending only on $\;a,b\;$ , or on $\;a,\,c=s\;$ and $\;m\;$ .

Comment: but a and b are outputs, not inputs (in my case). How can I calculate $x_0$ if I do not know these values?

Comment: @ChaseWalden Ok, then I get it now: in the third line above you have an equation relating $\;a,b\;$ with $\;n,s\;$, and two lines below, in the second line, you have an equaliton relating $\;a,b\;$ with $\;m,s\;$ . You can thus already write down $\;a,b\;$ depending on $\;n,m,s\;$, and from here take the last line and express $\;x_0\;$ (your $\;x\;$) as function of these $\;a,b\;$ which are functions of $\;n,m,s\;$

Comment: Yes and I have gotten that far on my own. The issue I am faced with is due to the $b^2$, there will be a $\pm\sqrt{...}$ somewhere when I solve the equation for a different variable. I am trying to solve this so that there is only one answer (instead of 2). I know this is possible since the possible values for x exist only between 0 and 1 in this scenario

Answer (score 0):

Some computation gives you:
$$b=2(m-s)\pm 2\sqrt{(m-s)(m-n)}\\
a=(n-s)-b=-(m-s)-(m-n)\mp 2\sqrt{(m-s)(m-n)}$$

We see that there are two solutions. However it turns out that one of them does not give us an $x$ which is in the interval $(0,1)$.

Remember that $x=-\frac{b}{2a}$. This is 
$$\frac{(m-s)\pm\sqrt{(m-s)(m-n)}}{(m-s)+(m-n)\pm 2 \sqrt{(m-s)(m-n)}}\\
=\frac{\sqrt{m-s}(\sqrt{m-s}\pm \sqrt{m-n})}{(\sqrt{m-s}\pm \sqrt{m-n})^2}\\
=\frac{\sqrt{m-s}}{(\sqrt{m-s}\pm \sqrt{m-n})}$$

where I assumed $m>s, m>n$. For the other case, you just need to switch the two terms of all the subtractions. The result is the following:
$$\frac{-(s-m)\pm\sqrt{(s-m)(n-m)}}{-(s-m)-(n-m)\pm 2 \sqrt{(s-m)(n-m)}}\\
=\frac{\sqrt{s-m}(\sqrt{s-m}\mp \sqrt{n-m})}{(\sqrt{s-m}\mp \sqrt{n-m})^2}\\
=\frac{\sqrt{s-m}}{(\sqrt{s-m}\mp \sqrt{n-m})}$$

You can see easily with the minus sign the $x$ values in both cases are greater than $1$. So only the plus sign works.

Comment: There is the other case where $m < s$ and $m < n$, which would use the minus sign. I am trying to eliminate the $\pm$ so I have one equation that will give me the solution

Comment: @ChaseWalden: Actually the other case is the same. I will add that case.

Answer (score 0):

We are given that a parabola has the equation $y = ax^2 + bx + c$
where $a$, $b$, and $c$ are initially unknown and to be determined,
that the parabola passes through the points
$(0,s)$ and $(1,n)$, and that the vertex of the parabola
(where its minimum or maximum occurs) is $(h,m)$
where $h$ is initially unknown but it is known that $0 < h < 1$.
(I use $h$ in $(h,m)$ where you used $x$ in order to avoid ambiguity with the variable $x$ used in the equation and because $h$ is a conventional name for the $x$ coordinate of the vertex of a parabola.)

Another form of the equation of the parabola is the *vertex* form,
$y = a(x - h)^2 + m$, where $a$ is the same parameter that occurs in the equation
$y = ax^2 + bx + c$.
(Conventionally we write $k$ instead of $m$ in the vertex form, but let's stick with $m$ since it is in the original question and does not create any ambiguity.)

The vertex form shows that our parabola is just a translation of the parabola with equation $y = ax^2$ by $h$ units to the right and $m$ units upward.
It follows that $s - m = a(0 - h)^2 = ah^2$
and $n - m = a(1 - h)^2$.
This implies that $s - m$, $a$, and $n - m$ all have the same sign
and that
\begin{align}
\sqrt{\lvert s - m\rvert} &= h \sqrt{\lvert a\rvert} , \\
\sqrt{\lvert n - m\rvert} &= (1 - h) \sqrt{\lvert a\rvert},
\end{align}
so
$$
\sqrt{\lvert s - m\rvert} + \sqrt{\lvert n - m\rvert} 
= h \sqrt{\lvert a\rvert} + (1 - h) \sqrt{\lvert a\rvert} = \sqrt{\lvert a\rvert}
$$
and
$$
\lvert a\rvert 
= \left(\sqrt{\lvert s - m\rvert} + \sqrt{\lvert n - m\rvert}\right)^2.
$$

But since $a$, $s - m$, and $n - m$ all have the same sign,

\begin{align}
a &= \operatorname{sgn}(s - m)
   \left(\sqrt{\lvert s - m\rvert} + \sqrt{\lvert n - m\rvert}\right)^2\\
&= (s - m)\left(1 + \sqrt{\frac{n - m}{s - m}}\right)^2.
\end{align}

From $s - m = ah^2$ we have
$$
h = \sqrt{\frac{s - m}{a}}
= \frac{1}{1 + \sqrt{\frac{n - m}{s - m}}},
$$
where we can rule out the negative square root because it is given that $h > 0$.

The vertex form of the equation expands to
$y = ax^2 - 2ah x + ah^2 + m$.
Setting coefficients equal in this equation and in
$y = ax^2 + bx + c$,
we find that
$$
b = -2ah = -2(s - m)\left(1 + \sqrt{\frac{n - m}{s - m}}\right).
$$

You already know that $c = s$, so now you have all three coefficients $a$, $b$, and $c$.

Answer (score 0):

You can use principles of linear algebra to find $a,b$, and $c$.

$ (0 , s),(x,m),(1,n)$

$c=s$

$ax^2+bx=m-s$

$a+b=n-s$

$ax^2+bx^2=(n-s)x^2$

$bx(x-1)=(n-s)x^2-(m-s)$

$b=\frac{(n-s)x^2-(m-s)}{x(x-1)}$

$a= (n-s)-b= \frac{(n-s)x^2-x(n-s)-(n-s)x^2+(m-s)}{x(x-1)}=\frac{(m-s)-x(n-s)}{x(x-1)}$

In general, for an nth degree polynomials, you need $n+1$ points to figure out its coefficients.

Answer (score 0):

The existence condition for such a parabola can be handled easily with a symbolic processor. The following MATHEMATICA script gives the condition.

```
conic[x_, y_] := {x, y} . {{a, b/2}, {b/2, c}} . {x, y} + {d, e} . {x, y} + f
equ1 = conic[0, s]
equ2 = conic[x, m]
equ3 = conic[1, n]
equ4 = b^2 - 4 a c
equ5 = D[conic[x, m], x]

Eliminate[{equ1 == 0, equ2 == 0, equ3 == 0, equ4 == 0, equ5 == 0}, {d, e, f, c}]
```

$$
\cases{
b^2-4ac=0\\
4 a^2 (m (2 x-1)+x (s (x-2)-n x)+s)+4 a b (m-n) (m-s)+b^2 (m-n) (m-s) (n-s)=0\\
}
$$

NOTE

`Eliminate` uses Groebner bases. Follows a typical case with

$$
\cases{
m=\frac 12\\
n=\frac 13\\
s=\frac 14\\
x=\frac 15\\
f = 1
}
$$

giving

$$
x \left(-\frac{25 \left(420 \sqrt{6}-1037\right) x}{16969}-\frac{20 \left(959 \sqrt{6}-2085\right) y}{16969}\right)+y
   \left(-\frac{20 \left(959 \sqrt{6}-2085\right) x}{16969}-\frac{48 \left(70 \sqrt{6}-3001\right) y}{16969}\right)+\frac{10
   \left(2338 \sqrt{6}-5207\right) x}{16969}+\frac{8 \left(105 \sqrt{6}-12986\right) y}{16969}+1=0
$$

and

$$
x \left(\frac{25 \left(1037+420 \sqrt{6}\right) x}{16969}+\frac{20 \left(2085+959 \sqrt{6}\right) y}{16969}\right)+y
   \left(\frac{20 \left(2085+959 \sqrt{6}\right) x}{16969}+\frac{48 \left(3001+70 \sqrt{6}\right) y}{16969}\right)-\frac{10
   \left(5207+2338 \sqrt{6}\right) x}{16969}-\frac{8 \left(12986+105 \sqrt{6}\right) y}{16969}+1=0
$$

[image]